# Persisting multiple data in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to persist multiple data in my database, I am new to Laravel, any idea would be appreciated.. thnx...
 so far this is my attempt but only the last input in my html form will be persisted.

**Controller:**

```
public function Somename(Request $request) {

    $count = 1;
    $subject = Subject::find($request->input('subject_id'));

    $question_count = Question::where('subject_slug', $subject->slug)->count();

    while ($count <= $question_count) {

        $tempanswer = Tempanswer::create();
        $tempanswer->temp_answer = $request->input('temp_answer');
        $tempanswer->question_id = $request->input('question_id');
        $tempanswer->student_id = $request->input('student_id');
        $tempanswer->subject_id = $request->input('subject_id');
        $tempanswer->save();

        $count++;
    }
```

**HTML Snippet**

```
{!!Form::open(['url' => '/examinations', 'method' => 'POST'])!!}
    @if(isset($questions))
        @foreach($questions as $question)
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <p>
                        {{$question->question}}
                        {!!Form::hidden('question_id', $question->id)!!}
                        {!!Form::hidden('student_id', $student->id)!!}
                        {!!Form::hidden('subject_id', $subject->id)!!}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <small class="text-blue">{{$question->choice1}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{$question->choice2}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{$question->choice3}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{$question->choice4}}</small>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" name="temp_answer" placeholder="Your Answer">
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
        @endforeach
    @endif
    {!!Form::submit('Finish', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-outline btn-sm pull-right'])!!}
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

Comment: actually its logical error, all data that saved in my database are the same,

Comment: the hidden input is comming from the loop so they have the same name sir, what would be the best solution or idea so that it will not inserted into database with the same data?